# javascript swap html input-date

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code - But when I swap values, both values become the same.

For example:

`datetimepicker = 25-04-18 17:32` and `datetimepicker = 24-04-18 17:32`, they have to be swaped, but the result is both are `24-04-18 17:32`.

Why does this happen?

```js
function swap() {
  var start = document.getElementById("datetimepicker").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("datetimepicker2").value;
  if (start.trim() && end.trim()) {
    var date_start = moment(start, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm');
    var date_end = moment(end, 'DD-MM-YY HH:mm');
    if (date_start > date_end) {
      document.getElementById("datetimepicker").value = end;
      document.getElementById("datetimepicker2").value = start;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input onchange="swap()" type="date" id="datetimepicker" />
<input onchange="swap()" type="date" id="datetimepicker2" />
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the code that sets the date - they are readonly now

Comment: @mplungjan the code is big, because I use a datetimepicker library. I didn't want to put more information that needed.

Comment: I would suggest renaming your variables.  Use something like `startDate` and `endDate`.

Comment: Your code as posted  INITIALLY works perfectly  if I remove the readonly.

Comment: I can see that this works, but I have the same code and it doesn't swap the elements...

Comment: @Lechucico The only difference I guess is that you have a datepicker registered on the elements then. Try to remove the datepicker and see if it works for you. Then figure out what the datepicker is doing

Comment: I was playing around with it and it does some strange things sometimes.  I wonder if maybe this should be a validation thing.  I'm assuming you don't want the start date to be after the end date.  Since someone might actually want this temporarily, and it would confuse users, it might be best to leave it as being available and you don't allow the form to be submitted because it fails validation at that point.  That's how this situation is handled most of the time.

Comment: @Xatenev I've removed the datepicker and it works. It seems that the datepicker is doing something with this.

Comment: For example, I'm a user and I select the 26th as the start date. Then the 27th as the end date. Then I think, well, maybe I should do this on the 24th and 25th. I then select the end date to be the 25th, but that swaps to the start date.  I then get confused as to what is going on, because my intention was to then change the start date to the 24th, but now the start date is the 25th, causing me to perform an extra click. I don't think this saves clicks, and I feel this is the reason you likely would want to implement this swapping of dates. So, validation failure is your best bet in my opinion

Comment: @adpro I'll go that way, because It seems that there is some kind of bug with that datepicker.